# Which cyclotomic fields are different?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

For $n$ a positive integer, let us write $\zeta_n = e^\frac{2 \pi i}{n}$, a primitive $n$th root of unity. It is clear that, if $m$ divides $n$, then we have an inclusion of cyclotomic fields
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n).$$
On the other hand, these inclusions are not always strict. For example, since
$\zeta_3  = \frac{1+i \sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\zeta_6 = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$, we have
$$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_6) = \mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{3}).$$
Does this sort of thing happen infinitely often, or are there just some coincidences among small numbers? If this continues, is there some way to know when a particular inclusion of cyclotomic fields is strict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equality $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ holds if and only if (WLOG) $m$ is odd and $n=2m$.

The following is from Marcus's *Number Fields*, p.19:

[image]

Comment: Hmm OK I have an argument for one direction, I think. Say $m$ is odd and $n=2m$. Consider the intersection of the multiplicative group of $n$th roots of unity with $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. This includes all the $m$th roots of unity but, in addition, the element $-1$. Now we have $n+1$ elements of a group of order $2n$, so we have generated the whole group and get $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$, as desired. I'll have to think more about the converse....

Comment: For the other way, you have $L/K/Q$ and neither extension is generated by a degree 1 polynomial but nevertheless one of them is degenerate. Try working with the degrees of the extensions.